# How do i place a marker at each coordinate point of a polygon?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create a polygon on a google map v3 and display a marker at each LatLng point of the polygon.  When you click on any marker an infowindow should display what coordinates the marker is at.

So far, I have plotted a polygon on a map and when you click on it it will display each of the coordinates of the polygon.  I need help with the next step.  I want to place a marker at each point that will display an infowindow when clicked telling the LatLng coordinates.  A link to what I have done so far is at http://www.sugarcube.ie/TEST/googlemaps/conor/polygonPoints.html
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you have the coordinates you're practically set:

[See here for making markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)

Also see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) for infowindows on markers

If you need any more help don't be afraid to ask, I have some sample code doing this I'm just not able to access it at the moment, sorry.

Here's the sample code from google on how to create an infowindow:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h2>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
    'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
    'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335 km (208 mi) '+
    'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450 km '+
    '(280 mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
    'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
    'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
    'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
    'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
    'Heritage Site.</p>'+
    '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
    'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> (last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title:"Uluru (Ayers Rock)"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

I think your problem lies with the event handler this example only deals with one marker and one infowindow, in your case you will need 2 arrays one for all the markers and one for all the infowindows and some kind of for loop whereby for every marker an event listener is created and it is tied to a specific infowindow, that is exactly what I had to do in my project, I promise I'll upload the code later today I just dont have access to it at the mo,

you're looking for something along the lines

```
    var markers = new Array();
    var infowindows - new Array();

//Fill the markers with the co-ordinates needed using push method
//then

for(i=0;i<markers.length;i++)
{
   google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
  infowindows[i].open(map,markers[i]);
});
}
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Hi there, I have created markers at each point of the polygon but I still need to create an infowindow for each marker.  Can anyone help.  I am close but it must be something simple I am forgetting.  See the link http://www.sugarcube.ie/TEST/googlemaps/conor/polygonPoints.html

Comment: Hi looking at your code I think your problem is that you are trying to dynamically change the dialog of one single infowindow, where it should be for each marker point there is also a corresponding infowindow object (i.e you create a new infowindow for each marker you have) so you should have an array of infowindows and markers and in your for loop tie each marker to its own infowindow.